# How to replace a substring in all the keys of a dictionary

Tags: python

I would like to change the name of the keys in my dictionary. I understand that this is not possible and that for this purpose
I would have to create new keys with the old values and delete the original keys (which I don't like too much) or
create a copy of the dictionary in a `for loop and in each iteration change the name of the key.

Current dict:

`{'form-4-var0': 125547, 'form-4-var1': 'NTMC-A935', 'form-4-var2': 'OTOGL'}`

Desired dict:

`{'var0': 125547, 'var1': 'NTMC-A935', 'var2': 'OTOGL'}`

Constraints: Preserving order if possible (not mandatory)

What I've tried:

I tried something like this adding some dummy text to each key name and it worked.

```
d1 = {'form-4-var0': 125547, 'form-4-var1': 'NTMC-A935', 'form-4-var2': 'OTOGL'}
d2 = {}
for key in d1:
    key_modified = //key without 'form-n-' substring
    d2[key_modified] = d1[key]
```

But how can I remove the substring `form-n-`?

Generally speaking n is only one digit, but it could be 2, 3, or m digits. Should I use some REGEX?

Is there a more pythonic way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your keys format is same you can split it with `-` and use last item of split

try dict comprehension like this:

```
d = {'form-4-var0': 125547, 'form-4-var1': 'NTMC-A935', 'form-4-var2': 'OTOGL'}

d1 = {key.split('-')[-1]:value for key, value in d.items()}
print(d1)
```

output is:

```
{'var0': 125547, 'var1': 'NTMC-A935', 'var2': 'OTOGL'}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use dict comprehension to do this. For removing the extra text you can use `.replace()`

```
old = {'form-4-var0': 125547, 'form-4-var1': 'NTMC-A935', 'form-4-var2': 'OTOGL'}
new = {k.replace('form-4-',''):v for k,v in old.items()}
```

Another option would be to use split, but this I don't recommend so much because information could be before `form-4-`

```
old = {'form-4-var0': 125547, 'form-4-var1': 'NTMC-A935', 'form-4-var2': 'OTOGL'}
new = {k.split('form-4-')[1]:v for k,v in old.items()}
```

outputs

```
{'var0': 125547, 'var1': 'NTMC-A935', 'var2': 'OTOGL'}
```

Comment: clean solution.

Comment: Thank you! If I'm not wrong, this solution works if the substring will be always 'form-4-...' but as I said, the substring can have m digits. can be form 1, form 2, form 33, form 495..

Answer (score 1):

The code I have written below makes a completely new dictionary with your desired results: keeping old values but changing the names associated with them, and it is still in the old order. Additionally, the old dictionary is still kept.

The first `for` loop goes through each of the dictionary's names and slices them twice. Once to get rid of the first hyphen (or separator), and twice to get rid of the second hyphen (or separator). This also means the dictionary names can be how ever long you want, but will always be separated by the hyphen(s).

The final `for` loop takes the new list of names and constructs a new dictionary with them and the old values.

```
old_dict = {'form-4-var0': 125547,
        'form-4-var1': 'NTMC-A935',
        'form-4-var2': 'OTOGL'}
old_dict_names = list(old_dict.keys())#get the names

new_dict = {}
new_dict_names = []


for i in old_dict_names:
    #First slicing, losing the first hyphen
    hyphen_1_pos = i.index("-")
    slice_1 = i[hyphen_1_pos+1:]
    print(f"First slice of {i} = {slice_1}")

    #Second slicing, losing all of the hyphens leaving the desired names
    hyphen_2_pos = slice_1.index("-")
    slice_2 = slice_1[hyphen_2_pos+1:]
    print(F"Final slice of {slice_1} = {slice_2}\n")

    new_dict_names.append(slice_2)#Adding the final result to a list

print(f"New wanted names for dictionary {new_dict_names}")

for nameIndex in range(0, len(old_dict_names)):
    new_name = new_dict_names[nameIndex]
    old_value = old_dict.get(old_dict_names[nameIndex])
    print(f"Old wanted value {nameIndex} for dictionary: {old_value}")

    new_dict[new_name] = old_value

print(f"\n\nNew dictionary as requested: {new_dict}")
print(f"old dictionary {old_dict}")
```

Hope this helps you, or any other people!